# scala generic function `not found: type ?`

Tags: scala, generics, kind-projector

When I use scala to create a function like this,It told me that `not found: type ?`

```
scala
    def save[
      K: SpatialComponent: TypeTag,
      V <: CellGrid: TypeTag: ? => TileMergeMethods[V]: ? => TilePrototypeMethods[V]
      ](id: LayerId, rdd: RDD[(K, V)] with Metadata[TileLayerMetadata[K]], method: KeyIndexMethod[K])
```

Can somebody told me how to resolve this?

Comment: What is ? refering to?

Comment: The first-level answer is because you're using `?` as a type and it's not defined. The real question is what you were intending by doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it,must add this code to build.sbt.

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
addCompilerPlugin("org.spire-math" % "kind-projector" % "0.8.0" cross CrossVersion.binary)
```

https://github.com/non/kind-projector